# How to make this flex box navigation menu dynamic

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I just started learning HTML and CSS, and I am building a website for practice. I finally got my header to look how I wanted it but now it gets all messed up when I resize the window to be smaller. I am using flex-box and I have two navigation links on the left, a title/logo in the center, and social media icons/links on the right.

[1440 x 900 Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqyuR.png)

[Shrunken down Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dI8va.png)

CODE:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta name="description" content="Genesis Barrios musician website">
    <meta name="keywords" content="musician, music producer, singer, artist">
    <meta name="author" content="Genesis Barrios">
    <title> Genesis Barrios | Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-3AB7yXWz4OeoZcPbieVW64vVXEwADiYyAEhwilzWsLw+9FgqpyjjStpPnpBO8o8S" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow:700|Rajdhani:700" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header-container">
        <nav>
            <div class="nav">
                <a href="#" class="home">HOME</a>   
                <a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
            </div>
            <div>
            <h1>GENESIS BARRIOS</h1>
        </div>
            <div class="social">
                <a href="https://www.youtube.com/genesisbarrios" target="_blank" class="fab fa-youtube fa-2x"></a>
                <a href="https://www.soundcloud.com/genesisbarrios" target="_blank" class="fab fa-soundcloud fa-2x"></a>
                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/renaissancegen" target="_blank" class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x"></a>
                <a href="https://https://open.spotify.com/artist/5p2tmJU9R8sopvcXdXBbsV" target="_blank" class="fab fa-spotify fa-2x"></a>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div id="video">
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/fbancNa0kwI"></iframe>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <p>Genesis Barrios Copyright &copy; 2018</p>
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body{
    background-color: #040404;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

header{
    background-color: #040404;
    min-height:80px;
    width:100%;
    height:20%
}

nav{
    display: flex;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    flex-direction:row;
    align-items: center;
}

a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.nav{
    font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
    font-size:30px;
    display: flex;
    margin-right:auto;
    padding: 0 1%;
}

h1{
    font-family: 'Rajdhani', sans-serif;
    font-size: 70px;
    color:#1ed2f4;
    display: flex;
}

.social{
    display: flex;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 4%;
 }

.fa-spotify, .fa-instagram, .fa-soundcloud{
    margin-left:10%;
}

.home{
    margin-right:50%;
}

#video{
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
    height: 0;
}

iframe{
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    border:0;
}

footer{
    background-color:#040404;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
    height:10%;
    width:100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.fa{
    color:blue;
}

a:hover{
    color:#1ed2f4;
}
```

Comment: I'd use a framework like bootstrap for menu responsiveness to save time, but give that you are starting with html & css it would be better to first do it the hard way before learning a framework, check this tutorial on how to make a responsive menu with pure css: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-create-a-fully-responsive-navbar-with-flexbox-a4435d175dd3

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do the following for your flexbox stylings. You don't really need "flex" on every element.

```
nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}
.nav, .social {
    display: flex;  
    flex: 0;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

You don't really need to have margin settings between the elements with flexbox. Flexbox takes care of the spacing if it is set right. You might just need some spacing around the nav-tag element.

Also, set responsive font variations for your GENESIS BARRIOS. 70px will be too big and overflow problems will occur. Even with text wrapping and such the big font won't easily fit and flexbox can only do so much.

Maybe a default size of maybe 28px then followed by some conditional styles like...

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    h1 {font-size: 36px;}
}
@media(min-width: 992px) {
    h1 {font-size: 70px;}
}
```

Another options which can be tricky is to use font sizes based on viewport width (vw)... but like I say this can be tricky and sometimes cause weirdness.